# Error while installing Network Simulator 2

Tags: software-installation, ns2

I had this error when I tried to download and install Network Simulator 2:

checking for gcc... gcc41
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/User/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See` config.log' for more details

How can I solve it? I really need to make this work because I am working on a project.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the 2014 - 2017 update "ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Install an ns2 compiler: `$ sudo apt install g++-4.8`

And build ns2 with the command `export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install`

ns2 INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing

---

Also ref. your closed question at stackoverflow :

> configure: error: Installation of tcl seems incomplete or can't be
> found automatically.

You cannot necessarily use ./configure in ns-2.35 ! That was for previous ns2 versions. The ./install command in ns-allinone-2.35 will take care of the right configuration sequence. Please do

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install
```

Comment: Any questions ? .... Then please update your question to include Ubuntu version https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336577/edit

Comment: Please see my edited answer about ./configure in ns-2.35 .