# Another error installing NS2

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ns2

A new error appeared when I tried to install NS2:

```
configure: error: Couldn't find http.tcl in    /http   /http2.5        /http2.4        /http2.3        /http2.1        /http2.0        /http1.0
```

Also:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

What can I do in order to fix these?

Comment: Repeat : You cannot use ./configure in ns-2.35 . ... Please see my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336577/error-while-installing-network-simulator-2/1336587#1336587

Answer (score 0):

for the configure error try `./configure --with-tcl-ver=8.5`

Comment: Could you expand on why this possible solution might fix the issue? This could help people in the future who face a similar issue.